# acts_as_list - Not dragging!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-list

I followed several tutorial to make this work, but I can't get draggable items.
Here's what i did:

added `gem 'acts_as_list'` in my GemFile and did a `bundle install`

added `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` to my application.html.erb

added an `:integer` column named *position* to my facilities;

added `acts_as_list` in my facility model;

added the sort method in my facility model:

```
 def sort
   @facilities = Facility.all
   @facilities.each do |f|
     f.position = params['f'].index(f.id.to_s) + 1
     f.save
   end
 end
```

added this in my view:

```
<ul id="facilities">
<% for facility in Facility.all %>
  <% content_tag_for :li, facility do %>
    <span class="handle">[drag]</span>
    <%= link_to h(facility.name), facility %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
</ul>
<%= sortable_element("facilities", :url => sort_facilities_path, :handle => "handle") %>
```

added this to the routes:

```
  resources :facilities do  
    collection do  
      post :sort  
    end  
  end
```

But in the end i have only a normal list, not draggable!
What am i missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there something you have to add to your model, like 'acts_as_list' or something. I've never used this but am using awesome_nested_set currently and that's how I drag all the nifty tree behavior into the model...

Comment: Yes, as i wrote i have "added acts_as_list in my facility model;"

Comment: ah, yes, sorry, I missed that. I was scanning for the code tidbit that would show that in action...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember does `acts_as_list` only deal with lists in Rails' models which means the *server side of things*. In order to make a list element draggable you'll have to include a *client side* library or plugin such as [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/). The gem itself doesn't (or at least didn't use to) include the functionality you're describing.

This library or solution will then

1. make your elements draggable and
2. provide you with a callback to update the order in the DB (usually using an AJAX call)

Comment: Yeah! The solution was to download the jQuery UI plugin, and invoke it using <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js" %>.